# Why a client should send something by websocket and not by ajax?

Tags: ajax, websocket, stomp

I'm investigating websockets and stomp protocol, it is a real innovation to send from server to clients but and I'm a bit surprised to find the send() method to send something from client to server.
If send() is an asynchronous call from client to server why should I use websockets instead of a standard ajax call?

Comment: because with send on client you don't necessarily have to expect or receive a response, possibly saving bandwidth.

Comment: An ajax answer can be empty with only the 200 reply code. Is it not the same? I made this question to understand if I well understand websockets.

Comment: No, because an empy ajax request still has to send connection info, headers, and sometimes cookies (unless you're using http2)

Comment: Also the convince of using only one protocol

Answer (score 0):

If you need a persistent, full-duplex connection between the client and the server, then you should use WebSocket.  If you are just blasting the same info from the server to a group of clients, use Server-Sent-Events which is a formalization of Comet (reverse AJAX) techniques... since Comet implementations weren't often interoperable.

Btw, WebSocket is a transport.  If you need a full-fledged messaging framework, you really should use the higher level APIs above WS and STOMP.  If you don't, you're basically reinventing a wheel that has been around for decades.